# Solr: How to Boost Query Results for Certain Filetypes

Tags: solr

Any idea how to boost a certain file type? For example, I want html files to have a higher score than all other files in my index.

Comment: How is your document structured? I.e. what field contains the type of the document? You can then apply a boost query against this field (`bq=content_type:text/html`)

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks, this worked! However, the score of html documents are now significantly so much higher that even the most irrelevant html page will have a higher score than the first way more relevant pdf file. Is it possible to tone down the boost a little?

Comment: You can change the boost by adding a `^<boost score>` - so `content_type:text/html^0.1` would reduce the score a lot. You can append `debug=all` to your query to see exactly how the score changes based on the boost you're applying.